# Can you return to earlier maps in Dishonored?

Tags: dishonored

I'm doing my first play through* of Dishonored and since I'm going the full-stealth route, the process will be slow.

I wondering though - *Can you return to earlier maps in Dishonored to grab goodies and upgrades you didn't fetch in earlier missions?*

Because if you can't I'll either need to lose some spontaneity of play to search everywhere, or read spoilery walk-throughs beforehand.

<sub>* Yes, I like waiting a few years before playing a game. Let them age like fine wine.</sub>

Comment: Related or Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89180/can-i-complete-optional-tasks-later

Comment: You know you have played too much Dishonored when you look at real buildings and think _Hmm, I could reach that rooftop with Blink._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot return to previous maps/levels in Dishonored. Having said that the game does feature multiple endings depending on how you play (e.g. how stealthy you are, how many people you've killed etc.)

So my recommendation is to play spontaneously in your first play through, and plan your subsequent ones if you intend to experience everything.